# Is Gilgulei Neshamot ever mentioned in Shas?

Tags: talmud-gemara, mysticism-kabbalah, soul, afterlife

I have heard that somewhere in Shas, there is a case of Gilgul neshama mentioned. Is there actually such a case, and where is this to be found?

Comment: There are many ways to understand the expression “gilgulei neshamot”. For example, in some places it is referring to how a person changes through the course of their life experience in this world. How are you intending your use of this expression?

Comment: @YaacovDeane my impression is that isn't the common understanding of the term...

Comment: @YaacovDeane what was the question

Comment: Shabbat 152aff.

Comment: @robev Following the Torah cycle as it coincides with this particular year, the Lubavitcher Rebbe discusses this exact subject in Torat Menachem Hitvadiyut, Vol. 4, pg. 229, for the 5th night of Hanukkah 5712. Although he brings the explanation in the context of Shulchan Aruch HaRav, Hilchot Talmud Torah, Ch. 4, sief 3, he explains this is also how it is taught in the 2nd & 3rd introductions to Sha’ar HaGilgulim as well as the parallel sources in Sefer HaGilgulim. It would appear that perhaps your impression is wrong.

Comment: @KapinKrunch Depending upon how you understand/intend the expression ‘gilgulei HaNeshamot’  would direct you to different source material in Shas.

Comment: @YaacovDeane the fact that your explanation is discussed doesn't change common perception

Answer (score 2):

No there are no explicit sources.  In fact Rav Saadia Gaon in Emunos V'Deos explicitly rejects this concept and considers it a non Jewish concept.  The Rashash in the back of the gemara in Bava Metziah 107 brings an indication from that gemara against concept of gilgulim.

(This does not mean other do not hold of the concept, in fact many Rishonim  ,and even Geonim do ,but a source in Shas is not explicit).

Comment: @sam סתירה קצת means ‘a minor contradiction’. That is not by any measure a “clear rejection”. It simply means the detail needs clarification. And the quote from Emunot v’Deot is also incorrect. You don’t understand what Saadia Gaon is saying there.

Comment: Please explain what Rav Saadia is saying then?

Comment: Sam you are completely wrong. The reincarnation that he is talking about is where the souls simply travel from one to another entity for whatever reason, without cause. That is very different from what is described in kabalah. Rav Saadia even wrote a perush on Sefer Yetsira, which mentions gilgulim. The Baal Shem Tov himself was a gilgul of Rasag, as the Ramchal revealed

Comment: I am unsure what you are talking about but it seems pretty clear from his writings that he rejects the concept in its entirety, and I do not understand how saying that the Baal Shem was a gilgul prove anything. Also see his third argument against gilgulim which seems pretty straight fwd,not sure how else you can learn Rav Saadia

Comment: What part was I unclear about? The process of reincarnation that he is talking about is not the same as reincarnation that is mentioned in kabalah. The halacha at the time was to not reveal kabalah to the public. The Arizal mentions Gilgulei neshamot alot, and revealed many secrets about it. It is now a well known pillar of Judaism, to deny it would be equivalent to heresy, as R' Chaim Kanievsky has stated

Comment: @sam To understand what Saadia Gaon is saying in Emunot v'Deot 6:8, disagreeing with the view of "some Jews", first requires reading carefully what he explains the soul is in chapters 6:1-3. The emphasis of Rav Saadia is that the soul is not material, nor feelings, nor intellect (even though it works with intellect). But is something that transcends all these materialistic categories. This is also the view of the Kabbalists. He does comment that souls are different from one Jew to the next and also that they akin to light but are actually higher than even that state of being.

Comment: @sam In 6:8, his disagreement is because the beliefs of "these Jews"  places the soul into these materialistic categories. The term which he uses to describe this is העתקה which means 'to transfer'. And that is the important concept to focus on. What he describes first as false is the "soul of Reuven transferring to Shimon and then transferring to Levi and then transferring to Yehuda. This is true. Reincarnation according to Jewish belief is not that the intact, complete individual soul moves from body to body. That is a non-Jewish belief. The Jewish concept relates to G-d maximizing reward.

Comment: @sam The 2nd thing Rav Saadia mentions as false is the concept of the Jewish soul occupying an animal body or vice-versa. This is also mentioned in Kabbalistic literature and rejected. In the only example I have seen that discusses this idea, it says that the Jewish soul is not compatible to occupy an animal body. That any such attempt results in spiritual pain forcing the soul to depart. It is unclear if some portion of the Jewish soul could perhaps occupy the body of some lesser creature or even an inanimate object. But a complete Jewish should clearly could not.

Comment: That does not explain his third argument ,from his third argument it seems that be clearly rejects the concept of gilgulim that regular people speak of ,coming back as another person

Comment: @sam And this leads to understanding what reincarnation according to Torah belief means. Only that portion of the individual soul that has not fulfilled its purpose during a given lifetime has the opportunity for reincarnation. Those perfected aspects do not return. What this means is that with each passing generation, the complete soul in a given body is actually a composite of many prior individuals. This is in keeping with the idea that כל ישראל ערבים זה לזה.

Comment: @sam You are misreading the text of Emunot v'Deot. He is speaking with precision about a particular belief that is in conflict with how he understands the soul in the opening chapters.

Comment: @sam Another  important detail in regard to Jewish belief about reincarnation is that memory of prior lives is, in general, not possible. This relates to the limitation imposed from one body to the next. Think of it as viewing the world with different prescriptions of glasses. Each body serves as a governor through which the occupying soul experiences the world. Change the body and the experience is completely different. Even if a complete, intact soul moved from one body to another (which doesn't happen), its perception and experience would be completely different.

Comment: I really am trying to understand your position but having a difficult time ,I read through Emunos Vdeos and it seems like we read 2 different books. How do you read his 3rd argument ?

Comment: @sam Please state precisely what language of his you are questioning. “His 3rd argument” is difficult for me to identify. I don’t know what you are asking.

Comment: It says  "hashlishi" והשלישי הבאתם את דבריהם על דרך ההוכחה, ואומרים כי הבורא מעשיו צדק, ואינו מייסר טף אלא על עוון שהזידה בו נפשם בזמן שהייתה בגוף אשר לפני גופם. ועל זה יש תשובות רבות:
הראשונה שהם התעלמו מאחד סוגי הגמול אשר הזכרנוהו9.
ועוד שאנו נשאל אותם על המצב הראשון, כלומר בתחילה כאשר נבראה, האם הטיל עליה ה' משמעת מסוימת או לאו. אם יאמרו לא הטיל עליה, הרי נפלו כל העונשים, מפני שלא היה צווי כלל, ואם יאמרו כן התחייבה, והרי הנפש אז טרם הונחה וטרם הוזהרה10. נמצא שהודו שהוא מחייב את בני אדם על העתיד, לא על העבר דווקא, והרי חזרו למה שאנו אומרים בגמול ועזבו את שיטתם שאין ייסורים אלא על מה שעבר.

Comment: @sam Once again, you aren't looking carefully at what Saadia Gaon is saying. He prefaces this 3rd category by explaining what it is. It is addressing very young children that suffer afflictions (only, not anyone else). This means does a newborn (or very young child) receive punishment for a transgression in a previous incarnation? Good question, but Torah teaches in many, many places that the newborn and very young child is "pure" (meaning free from sin, like the breath they use to say words of Torah has a level of purity that is greater than adults). And the Kabbalists hold this way too.

Comment: If a newborn or very young child is bearing afflictions, it is akin to the concept of the completely righteous, helping to minimize the burden & debt owed by those who are not righteous. And once again, this relates to reward & punishment and the concept that all Israel are mixed, one with the other. See the first section of The Way of G-d by Rabbi Moshe Chaim Luzzato for details.

Comment: @sam And this is, in fact, what the comment from Rabbi Shlomo of Strashun is bringing in his comments to Bava Metzia 107a in הגהות וחדושי הרש״ש which you quote. This doesn't deny or reject Gilgul HaNeshamot. It only clarifies what the proper understanding of it needs to be.